# Nice and Simple RegEx I can't work out

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to build a QueryString Reader from my app.config in the most part I have it working now I'm trying to add other config properties into the value E.G

```
<add key="Database[TableNames[Tracks]]" value="tracks" />
<!-- others... -->
<add key="Database[Querys[selectTracks]]" value="SELECT * FROM `{@Database[TableNames[Tracks]]}` WHERE track_id = '{0}'">
```

From the above I have the Key `Database[TableNames[Tracks]]` set and now I'm trying to use it in the value of `Database[Querys[selectTracks]]` but I can't figure out the RegEx I need to use to match it it cant be on all `{.*}` or `{[A-Za-z0-9]}` as this will match the String.Format `{0}` property and I don't want that it has to capture on the the `\{@.[a-zA-Z0-9!\}]\}` but that is not correct could some one give me the correct way to match my pattern?

I'm using http://www.regextester.com/ to test the RegEx Matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about what you are asking for here. if it's just a way to match the value within the backticks, will this do the trick for you?

```
\{@[a-zA-Z0-9\[\]]+\}
```

This matches the literal "{@" followed by 1 or more of the following characters "a-zA-Z0-9[]" and endind with the literal "}"

Comment: i was looking for just that just it could not be on the back ticks and needed the @ symbol inside it thanks that's perfect - 3 mins and i will accept

Comment: I'm ok at RegEx but when it comes to escaping i get a little lost :-)

Comment: Escaping can get very ugly very quickly!